# Can't delete file with specific pattern (ant delete file)

Tags: file, ant, task

I want to delete a file with pattern "name".* but it doesn't work.
I have tried this:

```
<delete file="${var1}/${var2}/${namefile}.*"/>
```

I want to delete the file ${namefile}.* in the directory "${var1}/${var2}".
How could I do it?

Thanks!

EDIT. Done with:

```
<delete verbose="true"> 
    <fileset dir="${var1}/${var2}" includes="${namefile}.**"/> 
</delete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done with:

```
<delete verbose="true"> 
            <fileset dir="${var1}/${var2}" includes="${namefile}.**"/> 
</delete>
```